# Call Another File's Class Function From JSX Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a chart rendered on my webpage and a button above it. In my chart.js file I enabled an object to appear on the chart by pressing a key. I would like the same thing to happen when pressing the button.

**chart.js**

```
...

onKeyPress(e) {
    const keyCode = e.which;
    switch (keyCode) {
    case 69: {
        this.setState({
            enableObject: true
        });
        break;
    }

onButtonPress {
    this.setState({
        enableObject: true
    });
```

**webpage.js**

```
...

render() {
  return(
    <div className="Button">
       <button onclick="????">BUTTON</button>
    </div>
```

`onKeyPress` is in a class component in chart.js. I imported Chart from chart.js in webpage.js but how do I map this function to my JSX button?

Comment: `onClick={onKeyPress}`

Comment: How do I define `onButtonPress` in my webpage.js? In my constructor? Still kind of new to this.

Comment: chart is a child of webpage?

Comment: Chart is a class in chart.js, onButtonPress is a function in that class. I import Chart from chart.js in webpage.js

Comment: You can't reuse this function, because it's a part of other component. If you are using Chart component inside webpage, then you need to move this function to webpage and pass it to Chart (to children component).

Comment: Oh I see. If you provide an example on how to do that I will accept your answer. `enableObject` is a prop of Chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart.js:

```
class Chart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.enableObject}</div>;
  }
}
```

Webpage.js:

```
import Chart from './Chart'

class Webpage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { enableObject: false };
    this.onKeyPress = this.onKeyPress.bind(this);
  }

  onKeyPress(e) {
    const keyCode = e.which;
    switch (keyCode) {
    case 69: {
      this.setState({
        enableObject: true
      });
    break;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Chart enableObject={this.state.enableObject} />

        <div className="Button">
          <button onClick={this.onKeyPress}>BUTTON</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    }
}
```